# In a db cluster, how might new slave/read instances be spun up "on demand"?

Tags: database

I would presume that unlike instances of web application servers, there would be something of a lag as the new database instance would need to be populated with currently existent data. And if this is a massive amount of information, wouldn't it be a relatively slow process?

Assuming the above is correct, my main question is how the reality of the lag would be mitigated in scenarios in which services require an increase of read-only db connections ASAP.

Comment: I imagine it would vary from one engine to another. Are you working with a specific database, such as MySQL?

Comment: I expect there is a pool of available follower machines, and when spinning a new one up one has to join a replication group first, and then announce its presence to the leader server. It might be worth setting up a demo either using small virtual servers (e.g. 512M each) or via Docker to see how it works, and what the spin-up time is for a new follower.